# Scan other application for input in X window

Tags: input, x11

What API calls or X window standard define ability to intercept user input from another applications?

How to register such callback in X window?

I see that this able to do Fvwm (and any other X window manager) and GoldenDict (scan for key-holding and text selection).

Also interesting do application lose focus during such callback execution?